# Ping to any name (existing or not ) on lan results in the same public IP

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, dns, ping

**Topology**- Frontier business DSL -> DLINK (DIR-655)  Frontier's DSL Modem includes a router we do not use other than to put one lan port to the dlink router's wan port.  The dlink sees this as local IP,<192.168.1.254> and we access internet through it.  6 Devices are on the DLINK lan.  all connected to the internet and all on the same subnet 10.0.0.2 (default gateway).

However on all the machines if you ping any name other than a IP addres, whether a valid device or a made up netbios name you get the following:  My results look like this:

```
ping gtfo (note: fake netbios name)

Pinging gtfo.home [23.217.138.109] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 23.217.138.109: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=51
Reply from 23.217.138.109: bytes=32 time=85ms TTL=51
Reply from 23.217.138.109: bytes=32 time=84ms TTL=51
Reply from 23.217.138.109: bytes=32 time=85ms TTL=51
```

I ping a machine on the network it looks like the above:

```
C:\Windows\System32>ping cm7shop  (real netbios name with static IP 10.0.0.205)

Pinging cm7shop.home [23.217.138.109] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 23.217.138.109: bytes=32 time=94ms TTL=51
Reply from 23.217.138.109: bytes=32 time=84ms TTL=51
Reply from 23.217.138.109: bytes=32 time=84ms TTL=51
Reply from 23.217.138.109: bytes=32 time=167ms TTL=51

Ping statistics for 23.217.138.109:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 84ms, Maximum = 167ms, Average = 107ms
```

If I ping the IP address of cm7shop I get this:

```
C:\Windows\System32>ping 10.0.0.205

Pinging 10.0.0.205 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.0.205: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.205: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.205: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.0.0.205: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 10.0.0.205:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
```

Nslookup give me this:

```
nslookup cm7shop
Server:  cm7shop.home
Addresses:  23.217.138.109
          23.195.69.108

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to cm7shop timed-out

C:\Windows\System32>nslookup 23.217.138.109
Server:  router.dlink.com
Address:  10.0.0.2

Name:    a23-217-138-109.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com
Address:  23.217.138.109
```

I ran a factory reset on the DLINK router and still have the same results as above.  I have rebooted all the PC's and updated all of their windows updates requirements.  2 pc's running windows 7 including cm7shop and windows 8.1 running on 2 other PC's issue happens from a win 8.1 to win 7 or win 7 to win8.1 or win7 to win7.  Everything worked without issue two days ago.

IF anyone can point me in a direction toward a resolution that would be much appreciated.  At this point I am unsure what to troubleshoot any longer.

This weekend I have full access and no employees in office so I can reset the entire network and the PC's as need be.

Will even bring in another PC and router to swap with just to try and isolate the issue.

*scratching head*

p.s. I would not have believed this had I not seen it

Comment: Can you post an accurate diagram of your network - including all routers and switches. Your description is confusing. Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry I found the issue the DNS server I was using was faulty I changed the DNS to a standard public one and everything started working properly

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue was due to DNS server.  Went to the router and changed the DNS server and everything started working properly.  Pings responded normally and netbios shares worked again.